# I cant read the image file in the particular directory

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I took some images in my camera and tried to resize them using opencv library but i think that i can't read the images I don't know the reason why.Thank you for the help in advance.

I have a python 3.8 version and the updated opencv library version.Not much of a background I guess.

```
import os,cv2
count=0
for file in os.listdir('E:\Projects\Python\Resixing images\Images'):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        print(file)
        img=cv2.imread(file)
        img2=img.copy()
        img2=cv2.resize(img2,(700,700))
        name="resize"+str(count)+".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(name,img2)
        count+=1
```

I receive an error message

P_20191107_214848_SRES.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\Python\Resixing images\image changing res.py", line 7, in 
    img2=img.copy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
[Finished in 9.7s]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
img=cv2.imread('E:\Projects\Python\Resixing images\Images' + '\' + file)
```

The problem was that you were sending only the name of the file to the python program, so the program tried to look for the image in the current directory and not at your specified path. The above change should fix the problem.

also, a good idea would be to have 2 // instead of 1 /, just to avoid any format specifier in the middle of things, or you could just use r to mention the path to be raw string

```
img=cv2.imread('E:\\Projects\\Python\\Resixing images\\Images' + '\\' + file)
img=cv2.imread(r'E:\Projects\Python\Resixing images\Images\' + file)
```

Comment: Suggesting code that's syntactically invalid doesn't seem very useful (try that first statement in an interpreter). You should consider rewrite the answer to avoid that issue and directly incorporate the part you mention at the bottom directly into the proposed solution. It's not just a good idea, it's a necessity. | However, a better approach to working with filesystem paths would be to use `os.path`.